Split a string escaping blank space
I have a list of vectors and want to split it into elements such as
a <- list(~X1+X2, ~X2+X3)

strsplit(gsub("~", "", a[[2]])[2], "+", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]

and it gives me
"X2 "  " X3 "

I want to have separate elements without blank spaces "X2", "X3". How can I escape the blank spaces?

all.vars(a[[2]])
# [1] "X2" "X3"


a) trimws() will remove leading and trailing whitespace from character vectors you pass in
b) you can avoid string splitting and gsubbing if you are dealing with formulas... you can pull out the term labels  :
attr(terms.formula(a[[2]]),"term.labels")


Simply wrap your code inside trimws() like so:
trimws(strsplit(gsub("~", "", a[[2]])[2], "+", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])

[1] "X2" "X3"

Hope this helps!
